# No rule to make target Makefile error in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I am new to shell script. I tried to run this makefile using shell script.
But is giving me this error

```
vedant@z510:~/workspace$ sh test.sh
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.
```

My  Makefile is

```
SRC=src
#OBJ=obj

FLAGS= -g3 -msse3 -g

SOURCE=     $(SRC)/main.c \
        $(SRC)/sgp_conv.c\
        $(SRC)/sgp_math.c\
        $(SRC)/magneticField.c\
        $(SRC)/sgp4.c\
        $(SRC)/dynamics2.c\
        $(SRC)/preisach2.c \
        $(SRC)/atmospheric_torque.c\
        $(SRC)/initialize.c \
        $(SRC)/ptangle.c\
        $(SRC)/effectMagnet.c\
        $(SRC)/print.c\
        $(SRC)/solarradiation_torque.c


OBJECT = $(SOURCE:.c=.o)


sim: $(OBJECT)  
    gcc -Wall -o demo $(FLAGS) $(OBJECT) -lm


$(OBJECT) : %.o : %.c Makefile 
    gcc $(FLAGS) -c  $< -o $@

clean:
    rm $(SRC)/*.o
```

and this is my shell script which I am trying to execute

```
alias proj="cd /home/vedant/version/version14.9_latest"
make -B
```

Please can you tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: What is `test.sh`? Those `alias` and `make` lines? That makefile is called `Makefile` correct? Are you expecting that alias line to change your directory in the script? Because it won't. Why are you using `-B` to make? You shouldn't generally need that. (Your makefile isn't written correctly so I expect you were using `-B` to work around that but fixing it is a better idea.)

Comment: I don't see any way you could get that output from the environment you've described.  There must be more to what you have than this.  Do you have another file named `makefile` or `GNUmakefile` in your directory?  There's no purpose in having the `alias` set here; it serves no purpose.  If you run `make -B` directly from the shell command line, not through the script, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: "alias proj="cd /home/vedant/version/version14.9_latest"" - Are you expecting this statement to get the process cd into the target location where makefile is present ?

Comment: test.sh is the file name of shell script

Comment: how to change directory and then run the make file because there is no make file other than this one .